# Is the Solaris libc based on the GNU libc?

Tags: linux, solaris, glibc

On Solaris：

#### basename.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int len = strlen(argv[0]);
    char *bsname = basename(argv[0]);
    printf("%s\n", bsname);
    printf("%d\n", len);
    return 0;
}
```

```
cc basename.c
ldd a.out
```

#### output：

```
libc.so.1 => /lib/libc.so.1
libm.so.1
......
```

On Linux：

#### basename.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int len = strlen(argv[0]);
    char *bsname = basename(argv[0]);
    printf("%s\n", bsname);
    printf("%d\n", len);
    return 0;
}
```

```
gcc basename.c
ldd a.out
```

#### output：

```
libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 
......
```

Is Solaris libc is based on GNU libc? Is `libc.so.1` on Solaris the same as `libc.so.6` on Linux?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Solaris C library is not based on the GNU C Library.   They both implement the C standard and POSIX interfaces and some other standards, but they don't share a common heritage beyond that.

Solaris libc.so.1 traces its history to the AT&T System V C library.

GNU libc.so.6 is based on glibc 2.0 or greater.   The earlier versions (e.g. libc.so.5) of the Linux C library were a fork of an earlier glibc 1.x release.

You will find that there are some difference between the two libraries.  For example, Solaris libc contains some string operations that glibc does not, `strlcpy()` being the most obvious to me.

**Additional note** (over a decade later): `strlcpy()` and `strlcat()` are coming to [glibc 2.38](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=454a20c8756c9c1d55419153255fc7692b3d2199)

Comment: Btw, there is [libbsd](http://libbsd.freedesktop.org/) to use library functions that originate from BSD like `strlcpy()` under Linux or other systems that don't have a strong BSD influence.

Comment: It doesn't look as though libbsd is available through opencsw, though that could mean they haven't had a request/need for it.

Answer (score 5):

Why?  Because they both call themselves `libc`?

No.

They're both called `libc` because GNU libc tries to be a compatible replacement for libc on proprietary Unices.  This is [the reason the LGPL license was created](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/bsdl-gpl/origins-lgpl.html).

A quick web search shows some of the [source code for Solaris libc](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/lib/libc/).  Picking [a file](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/lib/libc/common/sys/acct.s) at random, the copyright messages there say

```
/*  Copyright (c) 1988 AT&T */
/*    All Rights Reserved   */


/*
 * Copyright 2004 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All rights reserved.
 * Use is subject to license terms.
 */
```

so it should be pretty obvious the code doesn't come from GNU.

Answer (score 3):

Solaris libc is not at all based on GNU libc but they provide similar interfaces.